# How to re take move in 2D array for tic tac toe in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a tic tac toe game. It works perfectly fine except that I can't determine what condition should I write in order to re-take an invalid move.

This is how move is taken
(There is another public method to call these two private methods.)

```
private String getHumanMove()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Move: ");
    String str = in.next();
    return str;
}

private String getComputerMove()
{
    System.out.println("Enter Move: ");
    Random r = new Random();
    int r_row = r.nextInt(3) +1;
    int r_col = r.nextInt(3) +1;
    String str = String.valueOf(r_row)+ String.valueOf(r_col);
    return str;
}
```

This is the isValidMove() method

```
public boolean isValidMove(String move)
{
    int row = (int)(move.charAt(0)-'0');
    int col = (int)(move.charAt(1)-'0');

    if(board[row-1][col-1] == ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried using a while loop within `isValidMove()` but it didn't work.
Please help show me how to input the move again?

Comment: Is there some more code, ie. the main body? How do you make use of `isValidMove()`?

Comment: I'd think it would be easier to do a pre-check before allowing a move, instead of making the move, then trying to undo it if it's not valid.

Comment: @dave yeah there's main method in another class isValidMove() is called in another method of same class executeMove()

Comment: @Carcigenicate that's the thing. I can't understand how to undo the move and store new move

Comment: If you do what I suggested though, you won't be required to undo anything. You haven't given much detail about how moves are made, so I'll assume you have a `doMove()` method. If that's the case, all you need to do is something like `if(moveIsValid(move)) { doMove(move); }`

Comment: You probably also shouldn't print "Enter move:" in the computer move function; that will just confuse the user since they don't need to enter anything.

Comment: *"I tried using a while loop within isValidMove() but it didn't work."* any chance to be more clear on that part? What have you tried? What was the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted what the problem was. Go with @Fox's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
String move;
do { 
    move = getHumanMove();
} while(!isValidMove(move));
```

?

Comment: Whoops, I misinterpreted what the problem was. Ya, this would be the way to go.

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of the `while` btw.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ah damn the fingers. Thank you ;-)

Comment: Np. I'm just happy I'm at the point where I automatically see mismatched brackets XD.

Comment: @Fox thats the problem. it generates error if i write getHumanMove()  as this method is defined in other class (as per the requirement of question)

Comment: @Masu then you probably should update the question (not just comment) to reflect the structure of your code. You should probably add the main loop as well.